# List Index be out of range in a for i in List loop using IMAPClient?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, imapclient

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious.  I am trying to retrieve emails and iterate over them to find specific items in the text. The code runs but throws a 'List Index out of range' error part way through iterating over the items in the selected folder.  I don't see how that can happen when the list being iterated over is a list of index positions to being with?

I am using the IMAPClient package, and my script selects the right folder, and finds emails with a specific subject then returns a list

```
client.select_folder('WebsiteMessages', readonly=True)
result = client.search('SUBJECT "User Details"')
print(result)
```

this returns a list of items in the folder that match the search criteria

```
 [1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 36, 46, 48, 49, 51, 55, 57, 60, 61]
```

If I try to iterate over that list I get to a specific point and then get the list index out of range error.

```
for i in result:
    message = client.fetch(result[i], b'RFC822')
    print(message)
```

I don't understand how the error occurs seeing as the list is generated by the search?  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok - They are ID's not index's which explains it  - how to fetch specific ID?

Comment: `for i in result:` does not set `i` to `0, 1, 2`, etc.. It sets it to `1, 2, 9, 10, ...`. If you're trying to pass the value to `client.fetch` just use `client.fetch(i, b'RFC822')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, just a guess:

```py
for i in result:
    message = client.fetch(i, b'RFC822')
    print(message)
```

`i` already is already the value, using it as an index for the value is incorrect.

A second solution, which might be what you intended:

```py
for i in range(result):
    message = client.fetch(result[i], b'RFC822')
    print(message)
```

Comment: Thanks, both. you and Axe319 were right, and its not a list of indexes (as I'd thought) but a list identifiers.  But thanks, this should get me back on track